# NodeJS path.resolve doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, server, path

When I call `path.resolve("D:")`, it returns my Node.js project's root directory, which is `D:\Docs\NodeJS\DBTest` in my case, and it seems **strange** to me.

But `path.resolve("C:")` returns `C:\` as expected. `path.resolve("D:/other_folder")`  also works normally.

What can cause such a strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) mentions:

> If after processing all given path segments an absolute path has not
>   yet been generated, the current working directory is used.

I am not sure but I think issue is because you are trying it on windows. You can try [path.win32](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_win32)

Comment: Thanks for answer. win32 didn't help. Moreover - path uses win32 in my case, because there are such lines in path's source code: 
 
`if (process.platform === 'win32')
  module.exports = win32;
else
  module.exports = posix;`